# How to set duration for a ringtone?

Tags: android, alarm, ringtone

I want to set duration of ringtones. For example I want to stop it when it's played for 30 seconds. Do you have any idea how to do that? Because ringtones have no `setDuration` method or something like that.

```
Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
if (alarmUri == null) {
    alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
}
Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
ringtone.play();
```

Comment: If I remember correctly `ringtone.cancel();` should stop it. You just need to add a timer, once it reach 30 sec. you cancel the ringtone

Comment: @phil652you are right, btw using CountdownTimer is a beeter option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a countDownTimer as:

```
new CountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
}.start();
```

You can use onTick and onFinish, so cancel the ringtone when timer finishes.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use thread to stop your Ringtone

```
 Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(30000);  //30000 is for 30 seconds, 1 sec =1000
                    if (ringtone.isPlaying())                      
                     ringtone.stop();   // for stopping the ringtone
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        th.start();
```